# Unable to update the array in the current state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is my code. But when I'm trying to print the array, It's printing the empty array.

```
class FlatListItem extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            markers:[],
        }
    }

    changeSelectStatus=(key)=>{
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            markers: [...prevState.markers, key]
        }))
        console.log(this.state.markers)
    }
}
```

I want to push all the keys into markers array get it printed in the console (remote debugger).

Comment: `setState` is [async](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value), use the callback for console

Comment: what is key in coe ?

Comment: `setState` is not a synchronous function, hence you won't be able to immediately log the state

Comment: key is like the id of the selected item.@DhavalPatel on pressing the button the concerned id will be sent as an argument to the function.

Comment: @CharanrajhPepakayala Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

setState is an async function, if you wanna see the state changes you can pass a callback to see the state changes

```
class FlatListItem extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            markers:[],
        }
    }

    changeSelectStatus=(key)=>{
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            markers: [...prevState.markers, key]
        }), () => console.log(this.state.markers) )

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working. This is resetting the previous values.

Comment: this.setState(prevState => ({
            markers: [...prevState.markers, key]
        })

since you are setting the previous state(empty array) in the changeSelectStatus, it gives you the same state.....  what is the source of markers data? is it coming from props or an api response?

Comment: The keys are coming from the static data object. Anyway, we're updating the markers array, no? doesn't this reflect in the next event call?

Comment: no... initially, the previous state represents the state you initialized in the constructor, no matter how many times you call changeSelectStatus the previous state will be reassigned to the state.... since the markers values comes from static data object either you should send it down as props from parent and set it here as markers : [ ...props.markers, key] or import the static data object and use that variable to set the state...

Answer (score 0):

Your console log is generated before the state change to see if your code work maybe you should change your console log location

Example

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    markers: [...prevState.markers, key]
}), () => console.log(this.state.markers))
```

If the state not change after applying the code

Maybe you could try this

```
changeSelectStatus(key) {
        let x = this.state.markers
        x.push(key)
        this.setState({ markers = x }, () => console.log(this.state.markers))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `await` while setting the state like

```
fillArray = async () => {
    await this.setState(prevState => ({
        marker: [...prevState.marker, { id: 1, name: 'change' }],
    }));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.marker));
};
```

please check the [Demo](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/0FqhaCGmtV0xkgAx?open=Hello.js&deferRun=1) here

Comment: This is not working. This is also resetting the previous values. But when I'm sending the same key consecutively, the previous values aren't erasing. Suppose if  I pass 6 5 times, on the next time the console is printing 6 6's. After that if I'm passing 2 ,it is printing only 2.

Comment: In that case state must override somewhere in your code